# How return a value of type 'Func<TextWriter, Task>' in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

guys,

I tried to convert a function from mvc 4.0 in asp.net core 2.0 and get en error i am not able to solve.

the function is this :

```
    private static HelperResult Format(Func<dynamic, object> format, dynamic arg)
    {
        var result = format(arg);       // invoke function and return an oject 
        return new HelperResult(tw =>
        {
            HtmlString htmlString = result as HtmlString;
            if (htmlString != null) {
                tw.Write(htmlString);
                //return;
            }
            if (result != null) {
                tw.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result));
            }
            else 
            tw.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(""));
        });
    }
```

The error I get is :

'Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type
 Func <IO.TextWriter>, Task '

I understood I have to return a Task type but I don't know how.

Could someone give me a hand , thanks a lot
Joss

Comment: Have you tried using a return statement inside the lambda?

Comment: Show the constructor for HelperResult

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cause for this is that you aren't returning anything from, I assume its changed from an Action to a Func:

```
tw =>
    {
        HtmlString htmlString = result as HtmlString;
        if (htmlString != null) {
            tw.Write(htmlString);
            //return;
        }
        if (result != null) {
            tw.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result));
        }
        else 
        tw.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(""));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async lambda.

```
static HelperResult Format(Func<dynamic, object> format, dynamic arg)
{
    var result = format(arg);       // invoke function and return an oject 
    return new HelperResult(async (tw) =>
    {
        HtmlString htmlString = result as HtmlString;
        if (htmlString != null)
        {
            await tw.WriteAsync(htmlString.ToString());
                //return;
        }
        if (result != null)
        {
            await tw.WriteAsync(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result));
        }
        else
            await tw.WriteAsync(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(""));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sunshine. It seem to work ..even though it's not clear to me how this way the function return a task type.
Just because you set the async keyoword  the function return a Task. I was expecting to create some sort of new Task ....

Also .. there is a  synchonous  way to do the same thing. .. thanks a lot..

Comment: So the compiler implicitly makes the Task for you here since the lambda is marked as async, if there would be a return type the return would be a Task<T> where T is the return type. I would recommend reading up on async/await https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async If I had to guess someone updated this class to support this async behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have to take time to read deep about it. I am not so confident with async behaviour. Thank for your help.